# I would like to pull all attribute data from a specific category, using SQL or a PHP script

Tags: database, sql, category-products, category-attribute

I figured I could do a simple SQL query since this is on my development environment:

SELECT * FROM catalog_category_product WHERE category_id = 116

It looks like it returned the correct amount of products, but only with `category_id, product_id, position`.

So, I'm thinking I'll have to do a join with the cataloginventory/stock_item table. Is that right? Any help would be appreciated.

Or if that's a lot simpler: all I really need is the SKU number and quantity from that specific category 116.